# Map range of values to another range, non-linearly

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to map a value from one range to another. However, I would like to control the "curve"/"skewing of the mapping.

For example, I would like to map a range of values to the range [0.5, 2.0], such that a mid-point value in the source range maps to 1.0 in the destination range.

To continue with this example, for the following:

Src range [100.0, 1000.0]

Dst range [0.5, 2.0]

Desired output examples:

100.0 => 0.5

550.0 => 1.0

1000.0 => 2.0

(If I were to use a regular linear mapping -- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range -- then the midpoint value 550.0 maps to 1.25)

Thank you.

Allan

Comment: If you want the mapping to preserve the *order* of observations, then the mapping should be monotone increasing. There is a lot of literature on ways to interpolate points with a monotone function.  Is it sufficient for your purpose to specify the images of the endpoints and the midpoint?

Comment: I'll look up monotone increasing mappings, thank you. Also, what do you mean by "images"?

Comment: Defining the mapping of the original values ("domain" of the mapping) into the revised values ("range" of the mapping) gives us an image of *all* domain values.  I'm asking if it suffices for your purpose to control the image of the endpoints and the image of the midpoint.  A linear mapping only allows you the freedom to set the images of the endpoints (which can only be done by mapping endpoints of the domain to corresponding endpoints of the range, if you want the mapping to be monotone and onto).

Comment: Hi. So, yes, I think I just need to consider just the endpoints and the midpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty approach to controlling the monotone image of an interval so that the midpoint goes to a predetermined location is with a piecewise linear function.

Let the original values be the reference interval $[0,1]$, and suppose the new range should be $[a,b]$.  Since the function is to be onto and *order preserving* (monotone increasing), we will need:

$$ f(0) = a, f(1) = b$$

To give ourselves an extra degree of freedom we will specify $f(0.5) = m \in (a,b)$.  The piecewise linear function then consists of two segments of definition:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} a + 2(m-a)x & \text{if } x \in [0,0.5] \\
                       b - 2(b-m)(1-x) & \text{if } x \in [0.5, 1] \end{cases} $$

To guarantee continuity of the mapping it is enough to verify that both segments agree at the the point of overlap, $f(0.5) = m$.

For some applications it might be desirable to have a smoother mapping (this one is not differentiable at $x=0.5$) or to specify other properties (concavity/convexity/point of inflexion).  So this answer might be merely a stepping off point to explore more sophisticated mappings.

Comment: Let's assume input interval is [100,1000], the new range is [.5,2], and the desired midpoint is 1. Using 100 as a test value for x, using your formula, new_value = .5 + 2(1 - .5)100, which is 100.5 ... I would expect 100 to map to .5 ... am I computing this incorrectly?

Comment: You can handle this by first mapping $[100,1000]$ to $[0,1]$ by $g(x) = (x-100)/900$, and then following that with the piecewise linear function outlined in my Answer for $a=0.5,b=2,m=1$.  The first (linear) mapping sends midpoint to midpoint, $g(550) = 0.5$.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you.